# Why are my divs not aligning to the top?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to pull posts and show them after one-by-one, one-under-one. It's showing one-by-one perfectly, but it's not showing one-under-one. Here is the picture:

[image]

You can see there are some gap between 1st and 4th post. I don't want that gap. I tried `vertical-align:top` but it didn't work. If I try to apply `float:left`, it works like this:

[image]

I've tried to look it up on different sites, including Stack Overflow, but none of the solutions worked for me.

```css
.social-links {
  width:350px; display:inline-block; vertical-align:top; margin:5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-links" >  
  <iframe some-links-based-on-posts></iframe>
</div>
```

Here's the link, so that you can understand better: [ebosscanada.com/all-social-links/](http://ebosscanada.com/all-social-links/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to introduce "column-count"

Change the following:

```
.td-page-content {
    padding-bottom: 26px;
}
```

To:

```
.td-page-content {
    padding-bottom: 26px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count: 3;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it almost worked but for some reason, twitter embed doesn't work with this - https://www.ebosscanada.com/all-social-links/

Comment: Removing the `display: block;` attribute from `twitterwidget` seems to fix that issue. Possible to override it?

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set this style for `.social-links` container on your site:

```
.td-page-content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 100vw;
}
```

Comment: Should I apply this for .td-page-content and .social-links ?
I tried singly, it doesn't work on my screen resolution. http://prntscr.com/facp9q
Tried both, didn't work either